# Messenger Webview for Botframework V4

Tags: c#, facebook, webview, botframework

Can someone give me a head start in using Facebook messenger Webview? I have been researching it for days and I still don't have any idea on how to do it. And as much as I want give code here, I do now know where to start. The official docs are not helping me so much and I learn best by example.  I am using the C# Botframework V4 SDK.

Is it just a website viewed on messenger?
Do you need an existing website for it?

Comment: Are you trying to use the messenger extension that displays a web page over the conversation or are you just trying to direct the user to the web page in a new browser window?

Comment: I am trying to do the first one. Do you need an existing website for that? Or do you need to create a new one specifically designed for that webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook Webview that sits over the conversation requires a website that supports the Messenger Extension. You can either find a website that supports the extension or build your own and add the extension.

**Setting up Website**

You can add the Messenger Extension to your site by adding the following function call to your webpage.

```
(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/messenger.Extensions.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'Messenger'));

  window.extAsyncInit = function() {
    // the Messenger Extensions JS SDK is done loading 
  };
```

For more details, take a look at the Facebook Messenger Documentation on  [Adding the Messenger Extensions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions).

**Sending Template with Microsoft BotFramework**

There are several ways to bring up the Messenger Extension Webview with the Microsoft BotFramework, but the easiest option is to use a Facebook Button Template.  Add the URL for your site to the button template, and send it to the user by adding the template to the outgoing activity's channel data. See the example below.

```
var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();

var attachment = new
{
    type = "template",
    payload = new
    {
        template_type = "button",
        text = "Sign up for our mailing list!",
        buttons = new[]
        {
            new
            {
                type = "web_url",
                url = "https://mybot.azurewebsites.net/",
                title = "Sign Up!",
                webview_height_ratio = "full",
                messenger_extensions = true,
            },
        },
    },
};

reply.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new { attachment });

await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
```

Take a look at Messengers Documentation on [Button Templates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/button/) for more details. Note, make sure to [Whitelist](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/domain-whitelisting) any URLs you use with Facebook.

**Screenshot**

[image: Messenger Extension WebView]

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Thank you sir! If it is not much do you also know how to send and receive data from the webview to the chatbot?

Comment: Answering your follow up question would be too much code for the comments and would be better suited as another question. If  you open another issue, I’ll take a look at it.