# Converting facebook button template from json to c#

Tags: c#, botframework, messenger

Hello i am trying to do this template on my C# code for Bot Framework V4.
This is the code from facebook.

```
  "payload": {
  "template_type":"button",
  "text":"<MESSAGE_TEXT>",
  "buttons":[
    <BUTTON_OBJECT>, 
    <BUTTON_OBJECT>, 
    ...
  ]
}
```

And this is my attempt of doing it. I can't debug the error cause it only works on messenger. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

```
            Activity reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
            reply.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(
                new
                {
                    attachment = new
                    {
                        type = "template",
                        payload = new
                        {
                            template_type = "button",
                            text = "xx",
                            buttons = new[]
                            {
                               new
                                  {
                                       type = "web_url",
                                       title = "take test",
                                       url = "xx",
                                       messenger_extensions="true",
                                       webview_height_ratio = "tall",
                                  },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                });
            await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(reply);
```

Comment: What problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: Please don't paste code as images. Paste the actual code so that a) it is searchable and b) people can copy and paste to test your code in their environments.

Comment: Sorry, i am going to edit it now.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya my format is wrong. i can't debug the exact problem because i it is not producing an error on local emulator. Only in messenger.

Comment: @user10860402 see at this post i think it's can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44968612/9940803   https://stackoverflow.com/a/45894182/9940803

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128551/10708483

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Make sure to [Whitelist](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/domain-whitelisting) any URLs you use with Facebook. Note, they must be `https` URLs. Additionally, unless the website is configured to be a webview, you do not need the messenger_extensions and webview_height_ratio properties in the button.

```
var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();

var attachment = new
{
    type = "template",
    payload = new
    {
        template_type = "button",
        text = "Sign up for our mailing list!",
        buttons = new[]
        {
            new
            {
                type = "web_url",
                url = "https://mybot.azurewebsites.net/",
                title = "Sign Up!"
            },
        },
    },
};

reply.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject(new { attachment });

await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
```

Take a look at Messengers Documentation on [Button Templates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/button/) for more details.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Sir in the link you have shown. Does the webpage need to be hosted? Or can you just use an html that is not hosted? Thank you.

Comment: The site needs to be hosted unfortunately.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work. Looks like Facebook might have changed some things. This worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68685181/bot-framework-4-new-activity-with-channeldata-null-reference-facebook-messenge/68687418